# How do I apply two labels with the same value from regular expression

Tags: promtail

When using Promtail for log scraping, is there a way to configure two labels with the same value based on a single regular expression? So given something like this:

```
    - match:
        selector: '{app="my-app"}'
        stages:
        - regex:
          expression: '.*"(some-string)\":\s?"(?P<some_label>[0-9a-zA-Z-_;\.]*)".*'
          source: log
    - labels:
        some_label:
```

I would want to add a second label `some_other_label` with the same value. Is there a way to do this without having to re-parse the log just to give the capture group a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found it myself:

```
    - match:
        selector: '{app="my-app"}'
        stages:
        - regex:
          expression: '.*"(some-string)\":\s?"(?P<some_label>[0-9a-zA-Z-_;\.]*)".*'
          source: log
    - labels:
        some_label:
        some_other_label: some_label
```